# json encode php and google charts

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

```
$data = '{ 
    "cols": [   {"id":"","label":"ID","pattern":"","type":"string"}, 
            {"id":"","label":"Instant Background","pattern":"","type":"number"}, 
            {"id":"","label":"Red","pattern":"","type":"number"}, 
            {"id":"","label":"Green","pattern":"","type":"number"}, 
            {"id":"","label":"Blue","pattern":"","type":"number"} 
        ],

    "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"827075"},{"v":3992},{"v":3989},{"v":3994},{"v":3993}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"827070"},{"v":3974},{"v":3987},{"v":3985},{"v":3985}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"827070"},{"v":3974},{"v":3987},{"v":3985},{"v":3985}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"827070"},{"v":3974},{"v":3987},{"v":3985},{"v":3985}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"827070"},{"v":3974},{"v":3987},{"v":3985},{"v":3985}]}
    ]
    }'; echo $data;
```

ok the data works witht the echo when used on the google maps in this format so there is no issue there.

```
function drawChart(jsonData) {
      jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.mailboxmbe.com/jsongraph.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

PHP gets the data from an SQl statement and constructs the data as such:

```
$JSONObject1 = '{"c":[{"v":"'.$row["id"].'"},{"v":'.$row["sinstantBackground"].'},{"v":'.$row["sRed"].'},{"v":'.$row["sGreen"].'},{"v":'.$row["sBlue"].'}]},'.$JSONObject1;
```

Each Row has the following  **id,sinstantBackground,sRed,sGreen.sBlue.**

On the the Graph page **jsonData** holds the json string passed to it from the echo $data which is called via the SQL query.

What I would like to do is work out how to turn the json script in **jsonData** into a format where i can find out what the largest ID is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand the question but creating a DataTable should be enough :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Then have a look to the different accessor methods [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable).

Comment: Hi yes it currently works by simply redrawing the chart which has 50 points. Hence to update the chart with one additional point (the latest to the database) you pull 49 points that you already have. This seems like a waste of data. I wish to eventually pull only the needed points. To do that I need to know the largest ID that is in the chart.

Comment: You can find the largest ID from the "data" DataTable. Am I missing something?

Comment: var srows = data.getSortedRows([{column: 0}]);
var v = data.getValue(srows[srows.length -1], 0);